# Paypal transaction between two personal paypal accounts, System UnAvailable , please try again later

Tags: android, mobile, paypal

Context:
The Android mobile application needs to provide a platform to start a paypal transaction from One account to another account ( two personal accounts).

In order to do this, I am using Android Mobile Payment Library. Followed the documentation from the website
https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_android.pdf

I followed the steps as following
But it failed with "System UnAvailable , please try again later"". When I tried with ENV_NONE, it was successful.

Is this the way to do this? Or is there a way I can initiate a paypal transaction between two people and still get a confirmation to the app. If PayPal app is launched separately can 
the app get a confirmation?

1. create A PaypalPayment object and gave the recipient e-mail id

   ```
   PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
   newPayment.setSubtotal(10.f);
   newPayment.setCurrency("USD");
   newPayment.setRecipient("my@email.com");
   newPayment.setMerchantName("My Company");
   Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(newPayment, this);
   this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);
   ```
2. Had a Paypal button

   ```
   PayPal pp;
   pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, 
                 "APP-80W284485P519543T", 
                   PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);
       // Set the language for the library
       pp.setLanguage("en_US");

       // Some Optional settings:

       pp.setFeesPayer(PayPal.FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER);

       // true = transaction requires shipping
       pp.setShippingEnabled(true);

       CheckoutButton launchPayPalButton = pp.getCheckoutButton(this,
            PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       params.bottomMargin = 10;
       launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(params); 
       launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout)).addView(launchPayPalButton);
   ```

Comment: I read another forum and it said if the minSDKVersion of android is chanegd to 23, it should help.  I did that, it works fine now for sandbox. Before minSDKVersion was set to 26 in my android app